# Multiple Excels sources into separate sheets of destination Excel

Tags: ssis

In SSIS, I have multiple Excel connections. I wish to amalgamate these, so that the new Excel destination contains a number of sheets, each one directly coming from the Excel sources. I have a solution that works via a vba macro, but it isn't ideal. There must be a more direct solution.

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to use Merge Join in SSIS, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942421/combine-multiple-record-types-in-ssis-data-flow

Comment: Excel files have the same structure?